# Trigger manually ngFor or making it update DOM correctly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngfor

i have this code

TS

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then(res => {
  if (res.data !== undefined) {
    this.foodAllergies.push(res.data)
    if (this.categories.length === 0) {
      this.categories.push(res.data.category)
    } else {
      if (!this.categories.includes(res.data.category)) {
        this.categories.push(res.data.category)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <ion-col>
        <h3>{{category}}</h3>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let food of foodAllergies | categoryFilter: category">
            <ion-label>{{food.name}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

So whenever i add a new category to the categories array, the view updates correctly showing the foods that are in that category
The problem is that when i add a category which is already present in the categories array, the view doesn't update correctly because the second ngFor doesn't trigger it doesn't add the food with that category

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if() { ... } else { if() { ... } }` are doing the same thing, I find that strange.

Try updating `foodAllergies` in an `immutable` way (changing its reference) and see if that helps and kicks on change detection.

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then(res => {
  if (res.data !== undefined) {
    this.foodAllergies = [...this.foodAllergies.map(foodAllergy => ({...foodAllergy})), res.data];
    this.foodAllergies.push(res.data);
    // you can keep your if and else if but I have removed them here for this example
    this.categories.push(res.data.category);
   }
  }
});
```

For `...this.foodAllergies.map(foodAllergy => ({...foodAllergy}))`, depending on how many deeply nested objects/arrays you have in `foodAllergy`, you have to copy them immutably.

So say if `foodAllergy` looks like `{ name: 'Peanuts', x: [1, 2, 3], y: { a: 1, b: 2 } }`, it will become:

```
...this.foodAllergies.map(foodAllergy => ({
                                            ...foodAllergy, 
                                            x: [...foodAllergy.x], 
                                            y: {... foodAllergy.y } 
                           }))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i've resolved thanks to your answer. It wasn't necessary to use array.map but the solution that worked was:

this.foodAllergies = [...this.foodAllergies, res.data]

Don't know why with this.foodAllergies.push(res.data) didn't worked (maybe because creating a new array makes ngFor trigger instead of updating an existing one), but in this way it's working!